# Python win32event is not closed

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

I am creating win32event while run python file as service with the below code

```
#ServiceMain.py
import win32event
class A():
    self.__init__(self):
        self.exit_flag = win32event.CreateEvent(None,1,0, 'Global\\ExitFlag')
```

But when I am tried to close this event from another python file is not closed in while loop.

```
#close_event.py
exit_flag_exist = True
while exit_flag_exist == True:
    try:
        self.exit_flag = win32event.OpenEvent(win32event.SYNCHRONIZE | win32event.EVENT_MODIFY_STATE, 0,
                                      'Global\\%s_ExitFlag' % self.user_name)
        self.exit_flag.close()
        sleep(1)
    except win32event.error as e:
        exit_flag_exist = False
```

Can anyone help me why it is not close.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete example as top-level module code -- not snippets from a method.

Comment: @eryksun updated

Comment: Please, one file and no  snippets -- and preferably simplified without classes. Let's whittle the problem down to the bare minimum that's required to reproduce it, so we can clarify exactly what it is that you're misunderstanding here.

Comment: What exactly is not working ? How should it behave and how _does_ it behave? The 2 snippets seem unrelated (different event names). Check [\[MSDN\]: OpenEvent function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684305(v=vs.85).aspx): _"The event object is destroyed when its **last handle has been closed**."_ Are you also closing the event in _ServiceMain.py_?